# Some trouble occur while using Chinese coreference resolution in stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar

Tags: stanford-nlp

Given this Chinese sentence, "玛丽莲·梦露是一位美国女演员，我们都爱她。(English translation: Marilyn Monore is an American actress, and we all love her.)", that jar could run but could not output right result of coreference resolution. Nevertheless, if we replaced the comma in that Chinese sentence with a period, the jar would work well. Maybe that Chinese sentence is ungrammatical in view of English grammar, because it don't use a conjunction in between the two clauses. But, I have to say, the sentences like that in Chinese, have been widespreadly used, especially in informal situations. Who can tackle this problem? easing our work to handle punctuation manually. thanks